# Is it possible to show operations being done in php?

Tags: php

For example, suppose i have this very simple function

```
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;

    function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
}

    Sum();
    echo $b;
```

This normally would output 3 directly. But is it possible to make php show the operations being done, like 3 = 1 + 2? (similar to a console.log) Thanks!

Comment: You could just echo out the operation from within the function as you have done with the result in the last line...

Comment: Tools like xdebug give you step by step debugging access to your code

Comment: Also there is http://phpdbg.com/

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/expression-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the function a little bit to achieve this:

```
function Sum($a, $b)
{
    $c = $a + $b;
    return "{$c} = {$a} + {$b}";
}

$a = 1;
$b = 2;
echo sum($a, $b);
```

Note that I've changed the function to use parameters. Using `global`s is not a very good idea. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/1438393) to know why.

The above code outputs:

```
3 = 1 + 2
```

If you want your function to perform multiple operations, you can create a `switch` block and define the operations, and display the corresponding symbol (`+`, `-`, `x`, `÷` etc.)

Comment: Thanks very much @Arnal, that's exactly what i wanted to know. Thanks for the code improvment also!